# Magento Connect: Please wait, preparing for updates

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

Console stuck on "Please wait, preparing for updates..." when trying to install Beetailer using their magento connect [key](http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Beecoder_Beeshopy).

Any reason this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in extension key, you can download extension with this link after free register your name.